# How to end php session after 5 mins on inactivity in databse

Tags: php, mysql, session

I want to end php session , if there is a inactivity of 5mins . The inactivity is that if i dont find any values in the database then the session would end after 5 mins or else there is no problem

Comment: well thanks for ur replies bt this is not the exact solution i am looking for

Comment: What do you mean by `if i dont find any values in the database` ? Please explain your question with detail.

Comment: Basically i am building a online examination system , where then the teacher chooses a particular subject to start the exam , the name of the subject is kept in session , when the students choose  that subject to take their exam , then the names of the online students a kept in a table . My problem is if I dont find anyone not taking test on that particular exam , then the session would end after 5 mins .

Comment: @SnigdhodebMitra Do **AJAX**

Comment: yes, bt how ? i am not able to clear out the ways conceptually ..